# How to load external script in sequence

Tags: jquery

Do anyone has similar experience? I found the jQuery didn't load the script in order.  Below is the script I called, I have no idea what the sequence of the code be called. In code, the validation.js is called first and then the c_validation.js, but in the Chrome Javascript Console, the result of loading the script is inverted. Is it caused by the size of the script? How can I force the scripts be loaded one by one?

```
    $("#tab-4-content").load("/reg.php?id="+this.id+"&ads="+$(this).data('ads')+"&f="+$(this).data('file')+"&mid="+$(this).data('mid'));
    var url = "http://mydomain.com/validation.js";
    $.getScript(url) 
    .done(function() {
        console.log( "Success load validation");
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("Failed load validation");
        });
    var url = "js/c_validate.js";
    $.getScript(url)
        .done(function() {
            console.log("Success load c_validate.js");
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log("Failed load c_validate.js");
        });
    $.mobile.changePage("#tab-4");
    $("#terms").html("/dev/terms.inc.html");
}); // tab-3-content click

XHR finished loading: GET "http://dev.mydomain.com/c_by_cat.inc.php?id=code". jquery.js:10306
http://mydomain.com/validation.js js.php?id=code:92
XHR finished loading: GET "http://dev.mydomain.com/js/c_validate.js?_=1405324184667". jquery.js:10306
Failed load c_validate.js js.php?id=code:106
XHR finished loading: GET "http://dev.mydomain.com/reg.php?id=3&ads=1&f=3.png&mid=2". jquery.js:10306
Success load validation
```

Comment: Why would you load all your scripts with $.getScript ?

Comment: Why don't you just use `Script` tags?

Comment: The script will only be called on specific page depending on the visitor click it or not.

Comment: You simply issued two parallel AJAX requests. The order is undefined, depends on the server how fast it will process these requests (in particular the size of scripts is important).

Comment: I need to have the script called dynamically.

Comment: If you want to load scripts sequentially, then do it sequentially, i.e. call `$.getScript` inside `.done` callback of previous call.

Comment: freakish, yes, it seems to be, how can I force to called the script one by one or say one by another finished. Scripts are necessary to be called separately because script will be called somewhere individually.

Comment: freakish, your suggestion is good, let me try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you fire parallel requests. You can use something like that:

```
var get_scripts_in_order = function(urls, def) {
    if (def === undefined) {
        def = $.Deferred();
    }
    var url = urls.pop();
    if (url === undefined) {
        def.resolve();
    } else {
        $.getScript(url)
            .done(function() {
                get_scripts_in_order(urls, def);
            })
            .fail(function() {
                def.reject(url);
            });
    }
    return def.promise();
};

get_scripts_in_order(["script3.js", "script2.js", "script1.js"])
    .done(function() {
        console.log("loaded all scripts");
    })
    .fail(function(url) {
        console.log("fail: "+url);
    });
```

Note that the order of URLs is reversed due to `.pop`.

There's an interesting plugin for jQuery which may help you as well:

https://github.com/gnarf/jquery-ajaxQueue